# Show new mails at the top in outlook.com inbox

Tags: outlook.com, sorting

While trying to read inbox, I expect to view new emails from top down order. While it works in every other mail box, in outlook.com, my Hotmail doesn't show in that manner, if I have create new mail and he responds, I reply again, and so on so forth, the new reply email will only show at the same old reply mail he have has responded 1st time.

Is there a way for it to get onto the top so that I know there are new mails instead going all the way down?

Answer (score 1):

I will answer this question assuming that you're using `outlook.com`.

There are two things that could be happening here:

1- Your emails are not sorted by date. To fix this, go to your inbox and sort the emails by Date as shown here.

[image]

2- Your emails may be getting grouped by conversation. When this happens, messages are not shown individually and they may not be ordered as you expect them to. To fix this, you to your email settings as shown in these screenshots.

[image]

On the next screen:

[image]

And finally:

[image]

Hope this helps :)

Comment: it helps for sure Karancan. and i will try to change the option and see. btw, the group in outlook.com is like a thread in a forum right?

Comment: Roughly speaking, yes...

Comment: thank you very much! But i still wonder, in case that my emails are shown in groups, will the one group with the latest response go to the top? or it remains where they were, next move upwards?